# How to add constraint between two tables primary keys

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm new to stackoverflow, so in case of any error of formatting, or whatsoever, please let me know.

I'm a newbie in SQL so please bare with me.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    idUser INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Login(
    idLogin INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    idUser INT NOT NULL,
    dateOfLogin DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

I need to add a costraint such as `Users.idUser = Login.idUser`. How do I do it?

I've tried the following attempt:

Changing the create table to:

```
CREATE TABLE Login(
    idLogin INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    idUser INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(idUser),
    dateOfLogin DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

But the teacher didn't approve this solution, he wants the constraint to be added via a different Query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ALTER TABLE` to add a constraint to an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE Login ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES Users (idUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ALTER TABLE` instead

```
ALTER TABLE Login
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LoginUsersOrder
FOREIGN KEY (idUser ) REFERENCES Users(idUser);
```